# MVVM AsyncExecute causing lag

Tags: mvvm, icommand

AsyncExecute method causing lag in my treeview application when I am expanding a branch.
Important parts of my TreeView

```
public DirectoryItemViewModel(string fullPath, DirectoryItemType type, long size)
{
     this.ExpandCommand = new AsyncCommand(Expand, CanExecute);
     this.FullPath = fullPath;
     this.Type = type;
     this.Size = size;
     this.ClearChildren();
}
public bool CanExecute()
{
     return !isBusy;
}
public IAsyncCommand ExpandCommand { get; set; }
private async Task Expand()
{
     isBusy = true;
     if (this.Type == DirectoryItemType.File)
     {
         return;
     }
     List<Task<long>> tasks = new();
     var children = DirectoryStructure.GetDirectoryContents(this.FullPath);
     this.Children = new ObservableCollection<DirectoryItemViewModel>(
                         children.Select(content => new DirectoryItemViewModel(content.FullPath, content.Type, 0)));
```

> //If I delete the remaining part of code in this method everything works fine,
> in my idea it should output the folders without lag, and then start calculating their size in other threads, but it first lags for 1-2 sec, then output the content of the folder, and then start calculating.

```
     foreach (var item in children)
     {
          if (item.Type == DirectoryItemType.Folder)
          {
              tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => GetDirectorySize(new DirectoryInfo(item.FullPath))));
          }
     }
     var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
     for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
     {
         Children[i].Size = results[i];
     }
     isBusy = false;
}
```

My command Interface and class

```
public interface IAsyncCommand : ICommand
{
    Task ExecuteAsync();
    bool CanExecute();
}

public class AsyncCommand : IAsyncCommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    private bool _isExecuting;
    private readonly Func<Task> _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;
    public AsyncCommand(
        Func<Task> execute,
        Func<bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;           
    }
    public bool CanExecute()
    {
        return !_isExecuting && (_canExecute?.Invoke() ?? true);
    }
    public async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        if (CanExecute())
        {
            try
            {
                _isExecuting = true;
                await _execute();
            }
            finally
            {
                _isExecuting = false;
            }
        }

        RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecute();
    }
    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
```

> //I suppose that here is the problem cause IDE is hinting me that I am not awaiting here, but I don't know how to change it if it is.

```
        ExecuteAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, for some reason it is not blocking the expand button till the end of the size calculation, as I was trying to do by isBusy =true; line